# Can we have two different subscriptions inside a single app in ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am new to subscriptions. I came across a requirement where i need to sell two different products inside my iOS app.

1. So going with the Subscription model, can we have have two different
   types of subscriptions with different pricing in iOS? So **One
   subscription might cost him 2.99$** and **another subscription might
   cost him 1.99$**.
2. Can the user alter his subscription even before his subscription ends?
3. Is it possible to implement the **subscriptions on a quarterly basis instead of monthly or yearly**?

Is this possible to implement in iOS? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and reading,I got to know the answer. Below are my answers.

1. Yes, It is possible to have different subscriptions. If you want
   to support two subscriptions at a time, we need to add the
   subscriptions in two different subscription groups in iTunes
   Connect.
2. Yes, The user can downgrade or upgrade his subscriptions
3. Yes, It is possible to implement subscriptions on a quarterly basis.
   You have options to configure Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly and
   Annual subscriptions in iTunes Connect.

Hope this helps for anyone trying to implement the subscriptions for the first time.